# Push notification price/stock change for Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, amazon-marketplace

I know how to go and poll products to find out the price/stock myself but the best way would be to receive a push notification.

I see that there is a push notification service for Amazon Marketplace Web Services but I think that is for products I have added to Amazon myself, I want to receive notifications on any product of my choosing.

Is there a way to do that with the Product Advertising API?